# Want to add a "Loading..." status while page renders an unholy amount of HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function, that when a user clicks to open a menu of selectable divs, calls some AJAX to populate that menu with all the possible options. On a rare occasions it will append an unholy of options (35,000+). This can cause a 10-30 second delay, and during that time I am attempting to add a "Loading status".

**What I'd like to happen:**

- User clicks the menu
- Menu pops up
- Menu updates to include the "Loading..." status
- Eventually, the element loads with the crazy amount of options

**What currently happens:**

- User clicks the menu
- User has to wait 10-30 seconds while none of the other elements on the page are working
- Eventually it loads

Any ideas here? There are some things I'm going to be changing with this feature in the future, like only loading so many of the options into the HTML at a time and changing the menu. Also a secondary issue here is how none of the other items are interactable while the menu is loading, although the dynamic list problem could solve that too.

Here is a JSFiddle of what I'm attempting, and how it isn't working as I'd hope: https://jsfiddle.net/4dfwbj3x/1/

```js
var loaded = 0;

function RevealDivs() {
  console.log("Begin Load!");
  if (!loaded) {
    document.getElementById("ShowDivs").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("ShowDivs").style.innerHTML = "<div class=\"item\"> Loading... </div>";
    //The goal is to get this to load when the user clicks, then attempt to load the rest
    appendUnholyAmountOfDivs(3500);
    console.log("Divs loaded!");
    loaded = 1;
  }
}


function appendUnholyAmountOfDivs(numDivs) {
  var targetDiv = document.getElementById("ShowDivs");
  targetDiv.innerHTML="";
  for (i = 1; i <= numDivs; i++) {
    targetDiv.innerHTML += "<div class=\"item\">Item number " + i + "</div>";
  }

}
```

```css
#ClickMe {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}

#ShowDivs {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
}

.item {
  width: 180px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="ClickMe" onclick="RevealDivs()">Click to reveal
  <div id="ShowDivs">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Assuming the ajax call is quick enough, can you add pagination / filtering to the UI instead of rendering all 35k items all at once?

Comment: @Matthew definitely a direction I'm pushing to have this feature go in, for now this is the patch work solution I'm adding. Or are you thinking that's such a superior solution that I shouldn't even be bothering with attempting this?

Comment: @Nate I added one that shows loading until done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the interface a breather

```js
var loaded = 0;
var divs = 3500
const targetDiv = document.getElementById("ShowDivs");

function RevealDivs() {
  console.log("Begin Load!");
  if (!loaded) {
    document.getElementById("ShowDivs").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("ShowDivs").style.innerHTML = "<div class=\"item\"> Loading... </div>";
    //The goal is to get this to load when the user clicks, then attempt to load the rest
    appendUnholyAmountOfDivs();
  }
}


function appendUnholyAmountOfDivs() {
  if (loaded >= divs) {
    console.log("Divs loaded!");
    return 
  }
  targetDiv.innerHTML += "<div class=\"item\">Item number " + loaded + "</div>";
  loaded++
  setTimeout(appendUnholyAmountOfDivs, 10);
}
```

```css
#ClickMe {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: white;
}

#ShowDivs {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
}

.item {
  width: 180px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="ClickMe" onclick="RevealDivs()">Click to reveal
  <div id="ShowDivs">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here we hide and then show

```js
var loaded = 0;
var divs = 3500
const targetDiv = document.getElementById("ShowDivs");
const loader = document.querySelector("#ClickMe span");

function RevealDivs() {
  console.log("Begin Load!");
  loader.innerHTML = "Loading...";
  appendUnholyAmountOfDivs();
}


function appendUnholyAmountOfDivs() {
  if (loaded >= divs) {
    console.log("Divs loaded!");
    loader.style.display = "none"
    document.getElementById("ShowDivs").style.display = 'block';
    return
  }
  targetDiv.innerHTML += "<div class=\"item\">Item number " + loaded + "</div>";
  loaded++
  setTimeout(appendUnholyAmountOfDivs, 10);
}
```

```css
#ClickMe {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: white;
}

#ShowDivs {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
}

.item {
  width: 180px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="ClickMe" onclick="RevealDivs()"><span>Click to reveal</span>
  <div id="ShowDivs">
  </div>
</div>
```